# How to share CMSComponentData between independent components in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Let's imagine that we have CMS Component:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig(<CmsConfig>{
  cmsComponents: {
    CmsSupportComponent: {
      component: SupportComponent,
    },
  },
}),
```

But from inside we have to open another Angular component which also needs the same `CMSComponentData`. Simple Angular component relates to the same Angular module.

I know that we can do it via Angular Service, common for Angular manner (this requires some handy work). But maybe Spartacus has some approaches similar to:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  cmsComponents: {
    CmsSupportComponent: {
        component: SupportComponent,
        providers: [
        {
          provide: SupportComponentService,
          useClass: SupportComponentService,
          deps: [CmsComponentData]
        }
      ];
    }
  }
});
```

and we can share injected `CmsComponentData` via common Service for independent components.

**Update 21.01.2021:**

When we say - 'open' Angular component from inside CMS Component, it's meaning something like that:

```
this.modalService.open(SupportFormComponent);
```

As you can see `SupportFormComponent` is not child component and don't have any relationships with `CmsSupportComponent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular uses hierarchical dependency tree, so any instance that you can inject in a parent component, you can also inject inside child component, unless it's shadowed be new provider (but even then @SkipSelf may help).

So, as `CmsComponentData` is provided automatically by Spartacus, when instantiating specific cms component, it should be possible to inject it to any child component (inside this component) by just injecting `CmsComponentData` (you'll get the same instance).

In case of some complex configuration, when you are providing different CmsComponentData in child components, you can always wrap it into service (or provide as different token) in the first (top) component that gets it, but I think in your case it should not be needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately, it's a little bit different from what we really have. We don't have any relationships between these components, we just want to inject CMSComponentData into common Service and use it inside each component. I have updated the description by adding new inputs.

Comment: Considering that components don't have any relationships, problem resolved by passing CMS component data from one component to another via custom configuration and creating a new Injector for accessing this data inside separate component: this.sidebarService.open(SupportFormComponent, { data: this.component }).

Answer (score 0):

as defined in [Spartacus documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/#accessing-cms-data-in-cms-components):

> The CMS data that is related to a component is provided to the component by the CmsComponentData service during instantiation. The CmsComponentData service contains the component uid, and also data$, which is an observable to the component payload. By making use of the Angular dependency injection (DI) system, components and component-specific services can use the CmsComponentData.

it's recommended way to use Angular DI to inject CmsComponentData service and used in your components.

Best Regards,
Jerry

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Yes, we know that, but unfortunately we have a little bit different from 'standard' situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

this.modalService.open returns ModalRef. It is the instance creating component.

```
const  modal = this.modalService.open(SupportFormComponent);
modal.someProp = someData;
```

and in SupportFormComponent you should have public class property or @Input someProp

You can see example here https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/cart/add-to-cart/add-to-cart.component.ts#L103

Comment: Yes, it can also be an option but only for cases when you use ModalService as an approach for opening non-CMS-related component ;)

Answer (score 0):

Second way.

You can get data about cms-component by uid with help `CmsService` `getComponentData`

https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/core/src/cms/facade/cms.service.ts#L67

Comment: Do you have any data about cms-component? uid, typeCode, flexType?